# Slim adds extra spaces to text in button_to helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, slim-lang

In a slim template,

```
= button_to entry_vote_path(entry), method: :delete,
  class: "btn entry__vote_button __voted"
  |Unvote
```

It outputs

```
<button class="btn entry__vote_button __voted" type="submit">
                Unvote</button>
```

Pay attention to lots of whitespaces before the string "Unvote".

I tried removing these extra whitespaces and I found the following outputs without the whitespaces.

```
= button_to entry_vote_path(entry),
  method: :delete,
  class:  "btn entry__vote_button __voted"\
  do "Unvote" end
```

But this is a quite ugly code.

How can we remove those extra spaces in simpler way?

Comment: I don' t want "Unvote" in first argument of button_to. Because It outputs input tag with type=submit instead of button tag. I want use button tag.

Answer (score 0):

What about moving the classes forward and adding the text on next line like so (similar to what you have I know)?

```
.btn.entry__vote_button __voted= button_to entry_vote_path(entry), method: :delete
  | Unvote
```

Comment: Please add some explanation. Explain why your code should work.